# Firebase Hosting Deploy missing file

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Sometime when i deploy things to firebase hosting, i found that some file will not being uploaded to firebase.

In my public folder, there are 23 files

[image]

But when i deploy it to hosting, it only upload 22 files.
[image]

What i did before the deployment is just delete the previous version of hosting in the console.

I tried to re-deploy like 10 times but still the same.

Can some one expert can teach me how to solve this issue?

Thank you.

**Edited**
Here is the firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The missing file is `config.json` that placed in the `public/assets/config/` folder

**New Finding/Answer**
For those who got the same issue, you just have to wait more 15 mins and hard refresh(Ctrl + F5) the page again. Not sure is this caused by CDN or cache issue at server side. Because the other html & js code is updated, just my config.json not reflecting immediately.

Comment: The most likely reason is that the file is being ignored, because it matches a glob in the [`ignore` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#ignore) in your `firebase.json`. If that's not it, please update your question with your `firebase.json` and the specific if what precise file is being skipped.

Comment: updated the `firebase.json` in the post. The missing file is `config.json` that placed in the `public/assets/config/` folder.

Answer (score 5):

**New Finding/Answer**

For those who got the same issue, you just have to wait more 15 mins and hard refresh(Ctrl + F5) the page again. Not sure is this caused by CDN or cache issue at server side.

Because the other html & js code is updated, just my config.json not reflecting immediately.

Not sure is other people facing the same issue, but at least mine just work in that way.

Comment: The CDN should automatically be flushed before the deploy completes. But your browser (or other client) might be caching the file of course, which is outside of the control of Firebase Hosting.

Comment: But the JS code already updated. Only the config.json is not updated. I even tried with Incognito mode, as my understanding it won't be like this right?